# What's the fastest way to generate a 2D grid of values in python?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, multidimensional-array

I need to generate a 2D array in python whose entries are given by a different function above and under the diagonal.

I tried the following:

```
x = np.reshape(np.logspace(0.001,10,2**12),(1,4096))

def F(a,x):
  y = x.T
  Fu = np.triu(1/(2*y**2) * (y/x)**a * ((2*a+1) + (a-1)) / (a+1))
  Fl = np.tril(1/(2*y**3) * (x/y)**a * a/(2*a+1), -1)
  
  return Fu + Fl
```

and this works, but it's a bit too inefficient since it's computing a lot of values that are discarded anyway, some of which are especially slow due to the (x/y)**a term which leads to an overflow for high a (80+). This takes me 1-2s to run, depending on the value of *a*, but I need to use this function thousands of times, so any improvement would be welcome. Is there a way to avoid computing the whole matrix twice before discarding the upper or lower triangular (which would also avoid the overflow problem), and make this function faster?

Comment: `np.logspace` returns a Numpy array, so there's no point calling the array constructor on it. But how are you calling `F`?

Comment: the point of calling the array constructor is to transpose my vector x with shape (1,4096) and generate a matrix when I call F like F(50,x), is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can do `np.logspace(0.001,10,2**12)[None]` or use the reshape function which is more readable for people that are not friendly with Numpy. Note that there is an issue with the `)` in the function: there is one missing matching `(` parenthesis. Thus the current code does not work.

Comment: I edited the question to fix that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the multiplication before so to avoid multiplying a big temporary array (Numpy operations are done from the left to the right). You can also precompute `(x/y)**a` from `(y/a)**a` since it is just its inverse. Doing so is faster because computing the power of a floating-point number is slow (especially in double precision). Additionally, you can distribute the `(x/y)**a` operation so to compute `x**a/y**a`. This is faster because there is only `O(2n)` values to compute instead of `O(n²)`. That being said, this operation is not numerically stable in your case because of the big power, so it is not safe. You can finally use `numexpr` so to compute the power in parallel using multiple threads. You can also compute the sum in-place so to avoid creating expensive temporary arrays (and more efficiently use your RAM). Here is the resulting code:

```py
def F_opt(a,x):
    y = x.T
    tmp = numexpr.evaluate('(y/x)**a')
    Fu = np.triu(1/(2*y**2) * ((2*a+1) + (a-1)) / (a+1) * tmp)
    Fl = np.tril(1/(2*y**3) * a/(2*a+1) / tmp, -1)
    return np.add(Fu, Fl, out=Fu)
```

This is 5 times faster on my machine. Note there is still few warning about overflows like in the original code and an additional division by zero warning.

Note that you can make this code a bit faster using a parallel Numba code (especially if `a` is an integer known at compile-time). If you have access to an (expensive) server-side Nvidia GPU, then you can compute this more efficiently using the cupy package.

Comment: This was twice as fast for me, thanks for the detailed explanation! I'll mark this as correct if no one posts a faster solution that maybe avoids the unnecessary calculations by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

For a square (same number of points and same scale) grid:

```
lower_bound = -10
upper_bound = 10
xdim = 100
ydim = xdim

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(lower_bound, upper_bound, xdim), np.linspace(lower_bound, upper_bound, ydim))
z = foo(x, y)
```

Where x,y are each 100x100 arrays holding the coordinate in repective dimension (ie. inputs) and z holds the values of your function. Marginal performance gains are likely possible but this is the simplest and fastest to write imo.